# Maximum Likelihood Estimation for a t-distribution

Tags: statistics, optimization, numerical-methods, maximum-likelihood

How can you find the maximum likelihood estimate for the mean of a t-distribution?  I know there is not a closed form, but is there a way to do it numerically in R?

Or is there a way to do it partially by hand, then optimize the function in R?

Thanks!

Comment: Just in case this question gets no response after a while (say, a month), one might try the [statistics site](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: For a Student's t distribution the mean is 0 when the degrees of freedom parameter is greater than 1.  Are you contemplating a noncentral or generalized t-distribution?  If so, please add such information to your question.